# Passing multiple values to my view from mssql db

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I currently have a working code to query my db and pass values to the view in node.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  sql.connect(config).then(() => {
    return sql.query`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`;
  }).then(result => {
    res.render('newProject', {projects: result});
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
});
```

However can some one show me how to query 4 more tables and pass all those values to my view please?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain using [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in Node v7+:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  await sql.connect(config)

  try {
    const projects = await sql.query(`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`)
    const result2 = await sql.query(`another query`)
    const result2 = await sql.query(`another query`)
    const result4 = await sql.query(`another query`)

    res.render('newProject', {
      projects,
      result2,
      result3,
      result4
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

To run Promises concurrently, use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  await sql.connect(config)

  const promises =  Promise.all([
    await sql.query(`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`),
    const result2 = await sql.query(`another query`),
    const result2 = await sql.query(`another query`),
    const result4 = await sql.query(`another query`)
  ])

  try {
    const [projects, result2, result3, result4] = await promises

    res.render('newProject', {
      projects,
      result2,
      result3,
      result4
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: i tried the first approach and got the following error: https://pastebin.com/Uwn4A8rC do you what it might be ? im using mssql node module to connect with mssql server

Answer (score 1):

Each query returns a promise. To run all concurrently, you can use `Promise.all()`, which will trigger a response when they have all returned. For example:

```
sql.connect(config)
    .then(() => {
        const projectPromise = sql.query`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`
        const otherTablePromise = ...
        const anotherTablePromise = ...
        return Promise.all(
            projectPromise,
            otherTablePromise,
            anotherTablePromise
        )
    })
    .then(([projectResult, otherResult, anotherResult]) =>
        res.render('newProject', {projects: result})
    )
```